# In the desert, how didn't the male population grow to 1.5M over 40 years?

Tags: dor-hamidbar, pru-urvu

Here's my basic calculation:

- at the time of Yetzias Metzrayim (Exodus), the 600K males had 5 kids per family ([Targum Yonasan](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Exodus.12.37?lang=bi&with=Targum%20Jonathan%20on%20Exodus&lang2=en))
- half of the kids were males

(it is also highly probable that even if they hadn't they would have on average 5 kids in the first 20 years).

That totals to 1.5M boys (not counting Levis). They turned men 20-60 years in the next 40 years of wandering in the desert. Some casualties here (24K at G.Calf) and there (Midyan) do not add up to 900K.

I would expect the population to count at least 1.5M males at the time of entering the promised Land. The Torah only accounts for around 630K.

What am I missing?

Comment: Having references in your question would help see what you are speaking about. But kids also died during childbirth, from accidents, were being eaten by wild animals, etc.

Comment: @mbloch, the Clouds of Glory didn't protect them from wild animals? And if they weren't doing much physical labor in the desert, what accidents?

Comment: @Al Berko can you give us a more specific reference where the targum is?

Comment: @SamuelManuel Added to the text. That's pretty obvious that they could have at least 5 kids in the first 20 years of the wilderness.

Comment: @AlBerko thanks for the reference, I'll look at it now.

Comment: @mbloch with the reference added it seems to be a very good question

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Didn't 600k die because of the spies?

Comment: @DoubleAA I'm talking about their 1.5M children, the original 600K did die.

Comment: The 60 year olds' kids were in the 600k already

Answer (score 1):

About those 5 kids per family... there are other sources that counter this, and at least some of the males weren't married.

For new children that will be born:

> "לפי שהדרך גורמת לשלשה דברים **ממעטת פריה ורביה** וממעטת את הממון
>   וממעטת את השם"
>
> A journey lessens three things: **reproducing**, wealth and reputation.
>
> (Rashi Bereshit 12:2)

Comment: Even though they didn't travel very much (Rashi in the beginning if parshas Maasei), they thought they would, and for that reason they didn't give milah (yevamos 72a).

Comment: This is not an answer, the question wasn't how many children did they have, we take the number 5 for granted. The rest is also inapplicable here, as they stayed in the clouds, no lessening of wealth, health and reputation. You can mention that in comments though

Comment: @AlBerko It's not clear from your question that you take the 5-kids-per-family as simple historical fact. You do understand, that if you don't take it as simple fact, the question is not very strong?

Comment: You probably didn’t see the link to the Targum. 2. Your answer is inapplicable to the wilderness, it only speaks of a regular situation. 3. They had kids, and no reason to think that less than 5 per household. So do your math.

Comment: @AlBerko Do you think that **all the 600K** men were  married and had 5 children? it's more likely to read "every married men had five children"

Comment: There's no reason to think that all the men didn't have 5 kids during the 20 years. Don't you agree?